# In R Shiny, how to create a function for formatting numbers in renderTable output?

Tags: r, function, shiny, format

The below MWE code formats the numeric render table outputs. However you can see in the MWE that quite a bit of formatting code is repeated in (i) generating the default table that appears when first invoking the App, and (ii) generating the table after having clicked the "Modify" action button.

So I created a function `formatDF1` that captures this repeated code. But it doesn´t work! When I comment out the section of code between "BEGIN TEST..." and "END TEST" below, and un-comment out `formatDF1(df)` immediately above "BEGIN TEST...", the `formatDF1` function is completely ignored and the default table is generated without the desired numeric formats.

What am I doing wrong?

MWE code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

# Function that I'm trying to implement...
formatDF1 <- function(x){
  dfA <- format(x[1,],nsmall=0)
  dfB <- format(x[2,],nsmall=0)
  dfC <- paste(format(x[3,],nsmall=2),'%')
  dfD <- paste(format(x[4,],nsmall=2),'%')
  x <- rbind(x[0,],dfA,dfB,dfC,dfD)
  n <- dim(x)[2]
  colnames(x) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
  rownames(x) <- matrix3Headers()
}

matrix3Headers <- function(){
  c('Issuance period',
    'Scheduled amort period',
    '3m average XS trigger',
    'Percentage of capital')}

# Assigns default values to first column of input matrix grid
matrix3Default <- matrix(
  c( # Below are default values for table1
      1,
      24,
      0,
      100
    ), # close concatenate
    4, # specify default number of matrix rows
    1, # specify default number of matrix columns
    dimnames=list(matrix3Headers(), NULL)
  ) # close matrix function

# Automatically assigns names to column headers
colnames(matrix3Default) <- paste0("Series ",1:ncol(matrix3Default))

# Matrix input function
matrix3Input <- function(x, matrix3Default){
  matrixInput(x,
              label =  'Input series terms into below grid:',
              value =  matrix3Default, 
              rows  =  list(extend=FALSE,names=TRUE), 
              cols  =  list(extend=TRUE,names=TRUE,editableNames=FALSE,delete=TRUE),
              class =  'numeric'
  ) # close matrix input
} # close function

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel('Inputs'),
  fluidRow(actionButton('modify','Modify'),
           tableOutput('table1'))
) # close fluid page

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    mat3=matrix3Input('matrix3',matrix3Default),
    input=matrix3Default,
    colHeader = colnames(input)
  ) # close reactive values
  
  observeEvent(input$modify,{
    showModal(modalDialog(
      rv$mat3
    )) # close shown modal and modal dialog
  }) # close observe event
  
  output$table1 <- renderTable({
    
    if(!isTruthy(input$modify)){ # << Generates default table when first invoking the App
      df <- matrix3Default
      # formatDF1(df)
      # BEGIN TEST >>> Below indented code adds numeric formats to table output
        dfA <- format(df[1,],nsmall=0)
        dfB <- format(df[2,],nsmall=0)
        dfC <- paste(format(df[3,],nsmall=2),'%')
        dfD <- paste(format(df[4,],nsmall=2),'%')
        df <- rbind(df[0,],dfA,dfB,dfC,dfD)

      n <- dim(df)[2]
      colnames(df) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
      rownames(df) <- matrix3Headers()
      # <<< END TEST
      }
    else{ # << Generates table after user clicks "Modify" action button
      req(input$matrix3)
      rv$mat3 <- matrix3Input('matrix3',input$matrix3)
      df <- input$matrix3
      
      # Below indented code adds numeric formats to table output  
        dfA <- format(df[1,],nsmall=0)
        dfB <- format(df[2,],nsmall=0)
        dfC <- paste(format(df[3,],nsmall=2),'%')
        dfD <- paste(format(df[4,],nsmall=2),'%')
        df <- rbind(df[0,],dfA,dfB,dfC,dfD)
      
      n <- dim(df)[2]
      colnames(df) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
      rownames(df) <- matrix3Headers()
      rv$input <- df
    } # close else
    df
  },rownames=TRUE, colnames=TRUE) # close output$table1
  
} # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the function return the changed `x` -

```
formatDF1 <- function(x){
  dfA <- format(x[1,],nsmall=0)
  dfB <- format(x[2,],nsmall=0)
  dfC <- paste(format(x[3,],nsmall=2),'%')
  dfD <- paste(format(x[4,],nsmall=2),'%')
  x <- rbind(x[0,],dfA,dfB,dfC,dfD)
  n <- dim(x)[2]
  colnames(x) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
  rownames(x) <- matrix3Headers()
  x
}
```

and assign the output from `formatDF1` to `df` -

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

# Function that I'm trying to implement...
formatDF1 <- function(x){
  dfA <- format(x[1,],nsmall=0)
  dfB <- format(x[2,],nsmall=0)
  dfC <- paste(format(x[3,],nsmall=2),'%')
  dfD <- paste(format(x[4,],nsmall=2),'%')
  x <- rbind(x[0,],dfA,dfB,dfC,dfD)
  n <- dim(x)[2]
  colnames(x) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
  rownames(x) <- matrix3Headers()
  x
}

matrix3Headers <- function(){
  c('Issuance period',
    'Scheduled amort period',
    '3m average XS trigger',
    'Percentage of capital')}

# Assigns default values to first column of input matrix grid
matrix3Default <- matrix(
  c( # Below are default values for table1
    1,
    24,
    0,
    100
  ), # close concatenate
  4, # specify default number of matrix rows
  1, # specify default number of matrix columns
  dimnames=list(matrix3Headers(), NULL)
) # close matrix function

# Automatically assigns names to column headers
colnames(matrix3Default) <- paste0("Series ",1:ncol(matrix3Default))

# Matrix input function
matrix3Input <- function(x, matrix3Default){
  matrixInput(x,
              label =  'Input series terms into below grid:',
              value =  matrix3Default, 
              rows  =  list(extend=FALSE,names=TRUE), 
              cols  =  list(extend=TRUE,names=TRUE,editableNames=FALSE,delete=TRUE),
              class =  'numeric'
  ) # close matrix input
} # close function

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel('Inputs'),
  fluidRow(actionButton('modify','Modify'),
           tableOutput('table1'))
) # close fluid page

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    mat3=matrix3Input('matrix3',matrix3Default),
    input=matrix3Default,
    colHeader = colnames(input)
  ) # close reactive values
  
  observeEvent(input$modify,{
    showModal(modalDialog(
      rv$mat3
    )) # close shown modal and modal dialog
  }) # close observe event
  
  output$table1 <- renderTable({
    
    if(!isTruthy(input$modify)){ 
      df <- matrix3Default
      df <- formatDF1(df)
      df
    }
    else{ 
      req(input$matrix3)
      rv$mat3 <- matrix3Input('matrix3',input$matrix3)
      df <- input$matrix3
      
      # Below indented code adds numeric formats to table output  
      dfA <- format(df[1,],nsmall=0)
      dfB <- format(df[2,],nsmall=0)
      dfC <- paste(format(df[3,],nsmall=2),'%')
      dfD <- paste(format(df[4,],nsmall=2),'%')
      df <- rbind(df[0,],dfA,dfB,dfC,dfD)
      
      n <- dim(df)[2]
      colnames(df) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
      rownames(df) <- matrix3Headers()
      rv$input <- df
    } # close else
    df
  },rownames=TRUE, colnames=TRUE) # close output$table1
  
} # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]